# jquery effects (show)

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to just have something "show"? I know there's the effect called show, but I mean something with no animation. I know I could make the speed way fast or something. Or I could change the css from hidden or something. But does someone know of a built in method that does that? Same with "hide".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `show()` with no parameters. Same with `hide()`.

```
$('#item').show();
$('#item').hide();
```

Comment: +1 $('#item').hide(); == $('#item').css('visibility','hidden');

Comment: @Ben: Actually... I believe `hide()` sets `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: I recently experienced a situation when using show() and hide() with no parameters actually made the DOM element fade in – very quickly, but it was still visible as "animation". I'm not certain what was the exact reason for that, even though I believe this happened because I was viewing the site on a slow machine. I solved the problem by assigning 0 parameter, like this $('#item').show(0); Not sure if it's a totally appropriate solution, but it definitely worked in my case.